# Is there a bug in Mongo curosr batch sizes when used with text indexes?

Tags: mongodb, cursor

I have hit what looks like a bug in MongoDB (using server version 3.2.9).  The situation is as follows:

I have a collection with a simple index on an id field (which is a string), and a full text index including several fields (not including the id field), and I am performing a query that matches on the simple field (it's actually a user id in a collection with documents from many users) with a $meta projection (and query) to get results ordered by text match score.

If I impose a non-default batchSize on the DBCursor the find() gives me (Java driver) then the subsequent iteration of the cursor terminates after the first batch.  If I make no call to batchSize() then the iteration happily iterates across batches as necessary.

Digging a little deeper in the debugger it seems that the initial response form the Mongo server returns a cursorId if I left the batch size at default (0), but no cursorId if I try to request an explicit batch size.  The lack of a cursorId then causes the iteration to stop after it exhausts the initial batch.

Empirically this only happen when a text index is involved.

Is this a known bug or am I missing something?  If the former is there a known work around?